# Fancybox parent: 'form:first' breaking layering

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

I am using FancyBox and an ASP.NET UpdatePanel on my aspx page.

In order to get the UdpatePanel to post back to the server successfully, I added "parent: 'form:first'" when initializing the FancyBox. However, this causes the FancyBox to not be displayed on the top of the page.

I have tried upping the z-index of each layer/component of the FancyBox via Chrome's developer tools, but I cannot get the FancyBox to be on top of the screen when I have "parent: 'form:first'" specified (which is necessary for making the UpdatePanel work).

Any thoughts of what else I can try? I am using version 2.1.5 of fancyBox

Here is my FancyBox init code:

```
$("#webinar").fancybox({
    scrolling: 'no',
    titleShow: false,
    parent: 'form:first',
    onClosed: function () {
        $("#send_error").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show you FancyBox init code please?

Comment: Did you set/increase the `z-index` of the form itself? an element with `z-index` also relies on the parent's `z-index` to display properly. BTW, `onClosed` is not a fancybox v2.x callback, use `afterClose` instead.